Performance cost of keeping a mmap of a huge in-memory file (around 400MB) versus mmap and munmap several times
I'm facing a design issue regarding mmaping an in-RAM file (created in a tmpfs folder). The in-RAM file is around 400MB long, which in the worst case is of around 100k pages (unless the kernel chooses to use transparent huge pages of 2MB each, in which case it will drop to 200).
I don't know if keeping the mmap open, or whether to mmap it, then munmap it, and the mmap it again when I need it later. The file will be used in avalanches, like it could be use several times during some minutes, and then not used again for hours.
I'm not really really worried about the performance, but I'm curious to know what is the performance cost of mmaping and munmapping a big section consisting of thousand of pages dozens of times in intervals of milliseconds appart. What is the work that the kernel must do to do the mapping, setting the permissions of each page, etc?

Your use of "mmaping an in-RAM file" is confusing. Your wording implies that the file originally exists in a tmpfs or ramdisk. Where is this file stored originally, in a fs on a storage medium or in a tmpfs or ???

@sawdust It exists in a tmpfs folder. I have added a clarification in the question.

Tmpfs utilizes the page cache that @MarcoBonelli mentions in his answer. But that answer seems to assume that the file actually resides in mass storage, e.g. an HDD or SSD. So portions of that answer would not apply to your special case.

This highly depends on the specific environment your program is operating in.
In theory the kernel is smart and maintains a cache called "page cache" where recently mapped pages can technically sit undisturbed indefinitely after being unmapped from userspace programs. They still keep memory busy, but can be discarded at any time and written back to disk when that memory is needed. If you open htop or similar tools, you can see how much of your memory is being used for the cache:


The free command also shows this information in text form:
$ free -h
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            31Gi       5.4Gi        22Gi       164Mi       4.0Gi        25Gi
Swap:           31Gi          0B        31Gi

When you map a file, unless explicitly requested, it is usually not read into memory immediately, but on demand as each page is accessed. The first access on new mappings generates a page fault and only then the kernel loads the actual data into memory. Once this is done, the pages are also cached in the page cache.
Therefore, if you write a program that maps a large file, uses it, unmaps it and then re-maps it again to re-use it in a short amount of time, the second time the pages will most definitely already be in the page cache. In this case the only work that the kernel will need to do is fill the corresponding page table entries, which is fast.
However, the more time it passes between the unmap and the re-map, the higher the chance that the pages will be evicted from the page cache and written to disk. This is because almost any file-backed mapping uses the page cache, and memory (RAM) is usually limited. Programs that run alongside yours also continuously request new memory and the kernel may have to get some of it back by discarding pages in the page cache.
At the end of the day, whether the operation you describe (continuously unmapping and re-mapping) is fast or slow really depends on how much memory you have available and how busy the system currently is. What is definitely fast though, is to always keep the file mapped, and possibly lock it in RAM (mlock(2)) so that it is not swapped out. Of course, whether you can do this or not depends on the specific case, but that would be the best option purely from a performance point of view.

The kernel behavior regarding cached memory can also be altered through a few sysctl knobs, in particular:

/proc/sys/vm/dirty_background_bytes
/proc/sys/vm/dirty_background_ratio
/proc/sys/vm/dirty_bytes
/proc/sys/vm/dirty_expire_centisecs
/proc/sys/vm/dirty_ratio

See this documentation page where they are described for more info.

My main "worry" was about the cost of filling the page table with thousands of entries each time. I was aware about the behaviour of the page cache. I read in the docs about the cost of remapping an mmap just to change the access permissions (from read to read | write) and there is where I saw the mention about the filling all the page entries to change the permissions, like if it were something to be taken into account, which lead me to ask this question.

I wonder if mmaping an in-RAM file causes page faults (at first read or write) in case the virtual pages are not yet assigned, to do the bindings to the corresponding page cache entries or whatever, or whether the kernel optimizes that away by populating the page table in its "final form" inside the mmap call.

@ABu I can see time spent by the kernel to fill up 400MiB worth of page table entries being quite significant if you are doing it "dozens of times in intervals of milliseconds apart". You can test this by writing a simple program that only does this operation and running it under tools such as perf to check the amount of kernel and user time spent.

@ABu As per the second part: an initial mmap syscall inserts "fake" entries in the page table just to reserve the virtual memory area, it's the subsequent page faults that make the kernel modify the entries into their final form. You can however ask for it to be done immediately on mmap using the MAP_POPULATE flag.

Do MAP_POPULATE works in a blocking manner? (mmap does not return until all pages have been prefaulted?) Or is it more like a "prefetch" that happens asynchronously (in the sense that the kernel starts working on it "now" but not in a blocking manner)?

@ABu good question. It is blocking. Technically there is MAP_NONBLOCK to make it non-blocking, it used to cause non-blocking read-ahead exactly as you are saying, but nowadays it just makes MAP_POPULATE act like a no-op.
